# Rearanging div's to keep block as square as possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Scenario**

We have a website with a bunch of `div`s in them. `div`s aren't all the same size, but can only be 1 of 3 sizes. `div`s can be hidden and displayed by the click of a filter button. This hiding and showing is done with the [MixItUp](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) jQuery plugin. When all blocks are displayed, it looks like this:

[image]

**Complication**

There are two pages of these blocks. Pages can only be browsed if there is no filter selected. Let's say I select 'Filter 1', the filter 1 blocks show, and the rest hide, but now the blocks look like this (page 2 blocks in blue):

[image]

**What I need**

I need to have the blocks sort better. Like it's got to run down one side if needed, else as square as possible. In this case, the best solution would be to have it run down like so:

[image]

Is this at all possible with javascript/jquery/css? I also need to mention that this is a wordpress site built with a custom bootstrap 3 theme. So all this code is custom. I've tried CSS float to no luck. Any assistance with this would be appreciated.

Comment: try using `table` or `flexbox`, you will not need any plugin for that.

Comment: if you use bootstrap there is `pull-right`